# Assigning structure based on EPR spectroscopy

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, uv-vis-spectroscopy, ligand-field-theory, epr-spectroscopy

When given two copper(II) complexes - bis(N-3-chlorophenyl-salicydenaminato)copper(II) and bis(N-3-methylphenyl-salicydenaminato)copper(II) - how can you predict their EPR spectrum and hence their g average values based on their electronic properties? I am aware that bis(salicylaldiminato)copper(II) complexes have have a preference for square planar configuration, but is there any way to predict if the compound would assume a tetrahedral or square planar geometry based on its EPR spectrum?

bis(N-3-chlorophenyl-salicydenaminato) has an absorption peak in UV spectrum at 659 nm and bis(N-3-methylphenyl-salicydenaminato)copper(II) has it at 665 nm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use computational chemistry to predict the electronic structure of the different possible conformers and then use that to get a bunch of EPR parameters.
Specifically, you can use [ORCA](https://www.orcasoftware.de/tutorials_orca/spec/EPR.html#g-tensor) and [EasySpin](https://easyspin.org/easyspin/) to predict EPR spectra of your complexes and compare to an experimental spectrum.
You'll also get a bunch of other useful information about your complex, especially their relative stabilites.